# Calculus Trigonometric Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying to solve this particular problem and can not figure out where I have gone wrong in my solution. This is a picture of my solution, if anyone could help point out where I have gone wrong it would be appreciated.
[http://i.imgur.com/j0xGdM3.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/j0xGdM3.jpg)

Comment: I know that by expanding the correct solution out I get the same expression that I arrive at but it also has (-3/16) added onto it. So clearly I've lost information somewhere along the way, but I can't figure out how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your expression in your answer is not necessarily different from the answer.  Use the double-angle formula twice to try to recover an expression in terms of powers of $\cos{x}$.  But an easy way to see how the given answer is generated is by substitution:

$$\int dx \cos^2{x} \, \sin{2 x} = 2 \int dx \, \sin{x} \, \cos^3{x} = -2 \int d(\cos{x}) \, \cos^3{x} = -\frac12 \cos^4{x} + C$$